# $n$ different elements inside $k$ spaces without regards to order

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can I place $n$ elements (all different) into $k$ spaces, but without considering their order inside the spaces?

So, for example, with 5 objects numbered from 1 to 5 ($n=5$) and 3 spaces ($k=3$), I'll have 243 combinations.

```
0   0   5   combinations: 1
0   1   4   combinations: 5
0   2   3   combinations: 10
0   3   2   combinations: 10
0   4   1   combinations: 5
0   5   0   combinations: 1
1   0   4   combinations: 5
1   1   3   combinations: 20
1   2   2   combinations: 30
1   3   1   combinations: 20
1   4   0   combinations: 5
2   0   3   combinations: 10
2   1   2   combinations: 30
2   2   1   combinations: 30
2   3   0   combinations: 10
3   0   2   combinations: 10
3   1   1   combinations: 20
3   2   0   combinations: 10
4   0   1   combinations: 5
4   1   0   combinations: 5
5   0   0   combinations: 1

Combinations with identical elements: 21
Combinations with different elements: 243
```

If we consider the n elements to be equal, we have a $k$-tuple whose sum is $n$. So, according to stars and bars, the combinations are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.

But considering the elements to be different, the tuple $(3, 1, 1)$ has $\frac{5!}{3!*1!*1!} = 5*4 = 20$ combinations. So the final result (i.e. the sum of these combinations) with $n=5$ and $k=3$ (should) be 243.

I arrived at the result through brute-force. How can I do it neater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways to place $n$ distinct elements in $k$ spaces without regards to order is simply $k^n$. For example, in your case the number of ways is $3^5=243$.

The formula immediately follows from the fact that for each of the $n$ items we may choose any one of the $k$ spaces to put it in.